# Clicking on a div's scroll bar fires the blur event in I.E

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onblur

I have a div that acts like a drop-down.  So it pops-up when you click a button and it allows you to scroll through this big list.  So the div has a vertical scroll bar. The div is supposed to disappear if you click outside of the div, i.e. on blur.

The problem is that when the user clicks on the div's scrollbar, IE wrongly fires the `onblur` event, whereas Firefox doesn't.  I guess Firefox still treats the scrollbar as part of the div, which I think is correct.  I just want IE to behave the same way.

Comment: wow!  no answers still?  maybe I'll have to wait for the next version of IE.

Comment: It would help if you provided more details. What are you trying to do? What element is firing the blur event? Why is that a problem?

Comment: I edited the description to give more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem with IE firing the blur event when you click on a scrollbar.  Apparently it only happens n IE7 and below, and IE8 in quirksmode.

Here's something I found via Google

https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8887/tickets/248-results-popup-from-ajaxautocompleter-disappear-when-user-clicks-on-scrollbars-in-ie6ie7

Basically you only do the blur if you know the person clicked somewhere on the document other than the currently focused div.  It's possible to inversely detect the scrollbar click because document.onclick **doesn't** fire when you click on the scrollbar.

Comment: Observed on IE11 too.

Comment: The focus could be lost due to Tab also

Answer (score 19):

I've had a similar problem with a scrollbar in an autocomplete dropdown. Since the dropdown should be hidden when the form element it is attached to loses focus, maintaining focus on the correct element became an issue. When the scrollbar was clicked, only Firefox (10.0) kept focus on the input element. IE (8.0), Opera (11.61), Chrome (17.0) and Safari (5.1) all removed focus from the input, resulting in the dropdown being hidden, and since it was hidden, click events would not fire on the dropdown.

Fortunately, the shift of focus can be easily prevented in most of the problem browsers. This is done by canceling the default browser action:

```
dropdown.onmousedown = function(event) {
    // Do stuff
    return false;
}
```

Adding a return value to the event handler sorted out the problem on all browsers except IE. Doing this cancels the default browser action, in this case the focus shift. Also, using mousedown instead of click meant that the event handler would be executed before the blur event fired on the input element.

This left IE as the only remaining problem (no surprise there). It turns out that there is no way to cancel the focus shift on IE. Fortunately, IE is the only browser that fires a focus event on the dropdown, meaning focus on the input element can be restored with an IE-exclusive event handler:

```
dropdown.onfocus = function() {
    input.focus();
}
```

This solution for IE is not perfect, but while the focus shift is not cancelable, this is the best you can do. What happens is that the blur event fires on the input, hiding the dropdown, after which focus fires on the now hidden dropdown, which restores focus on the input and triggers showing the dropdown. In my code it also triggers repopulating the dropdown, resulting in a short delay and loss of the selection, but if the user wants to scroll the selection is probably useless anyway, so I deemed this acceptable.

I hope this is helpful, even though my example is slightly different than in the question. From what I gathered, the question was about IE firing a blur event on the dropdown itself, rather than the button that opened it, which makes no sense to me... Like my use of a focus event handler indicates, clicking on a scrollbar should move focus to the element the scrollbar is part of on IE.

Comment: After much digging into the issue, I finally found this solution, that works great with the jquery tokeninput plugin to prevent the dropdown from hiding when scrolling! Just attach it to the dropdown div like this: `$('.token-input-dropdown-facebook').mousedown(function() { return false; });`

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but I had the same issue and the current answers didn't work for me.

The hover state of the popup element works as expected, so in your blur event you can check to see if your popup element is hovered, and only remove/hide it if it isn't:

```
$('#element-with-focus').blur(function()
{
    if ($('#popup:hover').length === 0)
    {
        $('#popup').hide()
    }
}
```

You'll need to shift focus back to the original element that has the blur event bound to it. This doesn't interfere with the scrolling:

```
$('#popup').focus(function(e)
{
    $('#element-with-focus').focus();
});
```

This does not work with IE7 or lower - so just drop support for it...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y7AuF/

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent #popup from hiding if you press the tab key while hovering over it?

Comment: Yep, you'd need to add a keypress event to catch tab and hide manually just to be sure.

Comment: "This does not work with IE7 or lower - so just drop support for it..." - Love that one :D

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but since it still applies to IE11 here is what I did.

I listen to the mousedown event on the menu and set a flag on this event. When I catch the blur event, if the mousedown flag is on, I set the focus back. Since Edge, FF and Chrome won't fire the blur event but will fire the mouseup event (which IE won't), I reset the mousedown flag on the mouseup for them (on the blur for IE).

```
  mousedown: function (e) {
      this.mouseddown = true;
      this.$menu.one("mouseup", function(e){
        // IE won't fire this, but FF and Chrome will so we reset our flag for them here
        this.mouseddown = false;
      }.bind(this));
    }

 blur: function (e) {
      if (!this.mouseddown && this.shown) {
        this.hide();
        this.focused = false;        
      } else if (this.mouseddown) {
        // This is for IE that blurs the input when user clicks on scroll.
        // We set the focus back on the input and prevent the lookup to occur again
        this.skipShowHintOnFocus = true; // Flag used to avoid repopulating the menu
        this.$element.focus();
        this.mouseddown = false;    
      } 
    },
```

That way the menu stays visible and user doesn't loose anything.

Comment: I used this solution to fix my case. However I noticed IE *does* fire the `mouseup` event. The only issue is with IE firing a `blur` event (unnecessarily) when clicking the scrollbar, while other browsers don't. So, the `mouseup` part is useless. We only need the `mousedown` flag from the dropdown element and even less logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use focusout,  and focusin (IE specific events)

```
$(document).bind('focusout', function(){
     preventHiding = false;
     //trigger blur event
     this.$element.trigger('blur');

});

$(document).bind('focusin', function(){
     preventHiding = true;
});

$(document).bind('blur', function(){
       // Did anyone want us to prevent hiding?
       if (this.preventHiding) {
         this.preventHiding = false;
         return;
       }
       this.hide();
});
```

Comment: `focusout` & `focusin` are no longer IE specific events, so no go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probleme. Resolved by putting the menu in a wrapping (bigger) div. With the blur applied to the wrapper, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding the `tabindex` attribute set to `-1` to the `div` node.

Comment: That does not prevent the element from getting focused when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an IE issue.

It's more a case of how to design your interaction and where to handle which event.
If you have a unique css-class-accessor for the related target, canceling a blur event can be done by checking the classList of the event.relatedTarget for the element you want to allow or disallow to initiate the blur event. See my onBlurHandler from a custom autocomplete dropdown in an ES2015 project of mine (*you might need to work around `contains()` for older JS support*):

```js
onBlurHandler(event: FocusEvent) {
  if (event.relatedTarget 
      && (event.relatedTarget as HTMLElement).classList.contains('folding-select-result-list')) {
    // Disallow any blur event from `.folding-select-result-list`
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (!event.relatedTarget
      || event.relatedTarget 
      && !(event.relatedTarget as HTMLElement).classList.contains('select-item')) {
    // If blur event is from outside (not `.select-item`), clear the suggest list
    // onClickHandler of `.select-item` will clear suggestList as configured with this.clearAfterSelect
    this.clearOptions(this.clearAfterBlur);
  }
}
```

- `.folding-select-result-list` is my suggestions-dropdown having 'empty spots' and 'possibly a scrollbar', where I don't need this blur event.
- `.select-item` has it's own onClickHandler that fires the XHR-request of the selection, and closes the dropdown when another property of the component `this.clearAfterSelect` is `true`.