# Detect click event to prevent autocomplete list from closing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an issue in IE that is causing my autocomplete list to close when I click on the scrollbar, when the autocomplete element is on a dialog. It works fine for my other autocomplete inputs that are on the main page.

How can I add a click handler to detect what was clicked and cancel the close function if the target of the click was the scrollbar of the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Id love to just comment but since my renown isnt high enough here:

Try going trough this post it might contain solution for you.

[Clicking on a div's scroll bar fires the blur event in I.E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023779/clicking-on-a-divs-scroll-bar-fires-the-blur-event-in-i-e)

Comment: I came across that question as well. I am currently trying to create a widget which uses the jquery autocomplete as a base, and just add in some sort of blur/click handler.

Comment: Well u could try to check what was clicked. Like: 
function click(event){ if(event.target == $('html').get(0)){//something to prevent closing the list}}
Tough certainly a very dirty trick. Rather found a way to make IE treat the list like an dropdown or something